# if you know exact number of int you want in your list, how do you put it in one line

Tags: python, list

If I know that I need to put for example 5 numbers in a list, how can i put it in with just one line of input?

Sorry for beginner question, but i am new to this and I wasn't able to find an answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're answer is to vague. What scenario are you using this list for? Do you just want an empty list with a certain range? Why does it need to be a specific range in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it is unclear what you mean *exactly*, but I think you mean this:

```
myList = [int1,int2,int3,...]
```

Integers can be added into the list directly this way. I hope this helped!
Note that this goes for any type of value, not only for integers

In order to read user input of multiple numbers, you can do the following:

```
myList = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
```

If on Python2, you should use this instead:

```
myList = [int(i) for i in raw_input().split()]
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but this isn't what i had on my mind. I wanted user to write numbers in input in just one line (like, 1 5 9 3 7) and these numbers will be saved in list.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. You may want to try `myList = [int(i) for i in raw_input().split()]`. This asks the user to input an arbitrary amount of integers in standard input, separated by a space. This will be stored in a list, of course.
If you would want a different separator, you would use `.split('my_separator')`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted

Comment: You may want to accept it as the correct answer, so others can see the question has been answered. I'm happy to have helped you!

Comment: Yeah, didn't even know that was a thing. Anyway, thanks again and have a good day

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pythons built `range()` function. Which will return a range of numbers, on which you would then apply the Python `list()` function to.

For instance if you want a list between 1 and 100 you can do.

`list1 = list(range(1,101))`
This which would return all integers between 1 and 100.

In your case say you wanted 5 numbers between 0-5

```
five_numbers = list(range(1,6))
```

This would return `[1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: Thanks for help, but this isn't what i had on my mind. I wanted user to write numbers in input in just one line (like, 1 5 9 3 7) and these numbers will be saved in list.

Comment: @erikvalkovič Then use the `append()` function. For each number that a user writes, append it to your list. The last can be created empty, to later be appended to

Comment: Sorry, but this is still not what I wanted. Guy in thread above helped me already, but thanks for help anyway.